# Error in fread in C

Tags: c, windows, string

I want to read a text file (max length 300MB) and search a pattern (max length 100) in it. At first I used char text[1000000000] and fread to read the text file. But, I found that it is better to use the following code:

```
tFile = fopen("d:\\text.txt","r");
if(tFile==NULL){
    fputs("Text File Error",stderr); 
    exit(0);
}
fseek (tFile,0,SEEK_END);
tSize = ftell(tFile);
printf("%d\n",tSize);
rewind(tFile);
tBuffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*tSize);
if (pBuffer == NULL){
    fputs ("Memory Error",stderr); 
    free (tBuffer);
    exit (0);
}
tresult = fread(tBuffer,sizeof(char),tSize,tFile);
if (tresult != tSize){
    fputs ("Reading Error",stderr);
    free (tBuffer);
    exit (0);
}
fclose(tFile);
```

I also wrote free (tBuffer); at the end of my main(). I have 2 lines in my text file, each line with 10 characters. When I debug the program, tSize is 24 and result is 22. So, the program exits. I cannot understand what the problem is?????

Comment: Try opening it with `"rb"`? I wonder if there's some newline conversion going on there.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file in text mode on Windows, characters representing the end of line are converted: The Sequence CR/LF (carriage return / line feed) which represents end-of-line is changed to LF. This means that the amount of bytes you read from the file will not necessarily be equal to the size of the file.

If you open the file in binary mode (`fopen(filename, "rb")`), no such newline conversion will occur. Since you're dealing with a text file, it's probably better to open it in text mode but allow for the amount read to be less than the file size.